# display-buffer to generate buffer from other window

Tags: emacs, window

Every time I invoke vterm, it create a new window below as C :

```
   +------------+------------+    
   |    A       |     B      | 
   +------------+------------+  
   |            C            |      
   +-------------------------+
```

I am aware it invoke `display-buffer` to act this way.

How could let `display-buffer` to create a buffer from other window if it exist, rather than generate a third window?

```
   +------------+------------+    
   |    A       |      C     | 
   +------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure it with [display-buffer-alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Displaying-Buffers.html).

For example:

```lisp
    (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
                 '((lambda (buff-name _) (with-current-buffer buff-name (equal major-mode 'vterm-mode)))
                   (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-in-side-window)
                   (side . bottom)
                   (reusable-frames . visible)
                   (window-height . 0.4)))
```

Comment: ty but when call "vterm" , it still generate a third window. thank you again for the resource, I am learning now.

Comment: I personally still find this topic very confusing and my display alist is ever evolving. I have used [this reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cpdr6m/any_additional_docstutorials_on_displaybuffer_and/) to get more ideas on how to set it up.